# MS Access: Why wont my report display the proper heading?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, debugging

I have a form that generates a report based off what the user selects.

[image]

It is supposed to say "Completed: (The option that they chose)." It displays the proper heading when I choose one of the options, but if I choose the option of "Include All Training in Report" it gives me an error saying "Invalid use of null" and then brings this up when I go to debug.

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    Auto_Header0.Caption = "Completed: " + Me.OpenArgs
    
    
End Sub
```

The code for the form itself is this...

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub bBackCompletedTrainings_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "fTrainingMENU", acNormal
End Sub

Private Sub Command4_Click()
' Generate the report based on the control settings in the form
If cbAllTraining = True Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rAllCompletedTraining", acViewReport, , ""
    
    
Else
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rAllCompletedTraining", acViewReport, , "TrainingID = " & Me.lbTrainingID, , Me.lbTrainingID.Column(1)
    
    
    

End If

End Sub
```

Why is this happening? Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Sounds like `Me.OpenArgs` is null. What does that name refer to?

Comment: Use `&` for string concatenation. I never use `+` with strings because that is clearly a math operator.

Comment: @HackSlash It refers to the selection the user chooses. The `&` works, but it just shows "Completed: " and then nothing after it. I want it to say "Completed: All" or something to that affect.

Comment: Where are you passing the selected value from the listbox to the report Open Args? Is it `Me.lbTrainingID.Column(1)`  ? Because I don't think that has the value you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want it to work without trying to see whats causing the problem, then use;

```
= "Completed: " & Nz(Me.OpenArgs,"All")
```